# How to dynamically set histogram binwidth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a total R noob learning ggplot.
I don't understand why the first snippet works while the second doesn't. I wanted to find a good binwidth without guessing, so I tried an experiment that didn't work.

```
library(ggplot2)
attach(diamonds)
d <- diamonds
x <- ggplot(d, aes(x = price))
x <- x + geom_histogram(binwidth = 50)
x
# worked fine, but using the sequence and substituting i didn't
i <- seq(1, 101, by = 10)  #tried to avoid the first arg as zero, but didn't work
x <- ggplot(d, aes(x = price))
x <- x + geom_histogram(binwidth = i) 
x
```

the second throws an error

```
Error in seq.default(round_any(range[1], size, floor), round_any(range[2],  : 
  'from' must be of length 1
Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : 
  argument "env" is missing, with no default
```

I don't understand what it wants.
Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to use `lapply` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
i<-seq(1,101, by=10)  
x1<- ggplot(d, aes(x=price))
x2<-lapply(i,function(i)
x1+geom_histogram(binwidth=i)

)
To access each plot:
x2[[1]] # for bw 1
x2[[2]] #bw 11 and so on
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Metrics, I found it useful and very instructive.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to consider the package `manipulate` if you are using [`RStudio`](http://www.rstudio.com):

```
install.packages("manipulate")
library(manipulate)
library(ggplot2)

df <- diamonds

manipulate(
  ggplot(df, aes(x = price)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = mybinwidth),
  mybinwidth = slider(10, 100, step = 10, initial = 20)
)
```

[image: Picture of Manipulate]

Aside: Please note that you do not need to `attach(diamonds)` if you are using `ggplot2`. Moreover, many people will argue against using `attach` altogether - and you may want to break the habit now. For example, the following works just fine:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = price)) + geom_histogram()
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks very much @Jason, your solution it is an eye opener! Also thanks for the tip about attach...I  just didn't know any better.

Comment: @user4056279 glad I could help. Learning R is a marathon, not a sprint.

Comment: For other noobs hacking their way to R nirvana, I found this after searching why not to attach. It lists several safer alternatives. http://www.r-bloggers.com/to-attach-or-not-attach-that-is-the-question/